# Power Query Add Conditional Column

Tags: excel, powerquery

Assume I have 3 countries:

| Country |
| --- |
| US |
| UK |
| JP |

And each of them has their famous cities for example:
US - New York, Seattle, Miami
UK - London, Birmingham
JP - Tokyo, Osaka

Now what I want to do is to add a conditional column while based on the country and list out the cities for each:

| Country | City |
| --- | --- |
| US | New York |
| US | Seattle |
| US | Miami |
| UK | London |
| UK | Birmingham |
| JP | Tokyo |
| JP | Osaka |

I tried to do something like but I guess it's mistaken:

```
let

//reflect actual data source

    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Country", type text}),


//Add columns with city
    #"Add City" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "City", 
        each if "Country" = "US" then each {"New York","Seattle","Miami"}
        else if "Country" = "UK" then each {"London","Birmingham"}
        else {"Tokyo","Osaka"}),

//Expand the lists to new rows
    #"Expanded City" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Add City", "City")
in
    #"Expanded City"
```

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so please toggle the checkmark to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 1):

This would be the correct version of your code, the main difference being using [Country] in place of "Country"

```
let  

//reflect actual data source
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Country", type text}}),

//Add columns with city
#"Add City" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "City", 
    each if [Country] = "US" then {"New York","Seattle","Miami"}
    else if [Country] = "UK" then  {"London","Birmingham"}
    else {"Tokyo","Osaka"}),

//Expand the lists to new rows
#"Expanded City" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Add City", "City")
in  #"Expanded City"
```

That said, it is not the way to go.  Create a separate Table, do a (home .. merge) merge using left outer join on the Country field

[image]

Then expand the City field

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"Country"}, Table2, {"Country"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"City"}, {"City"})
in  #"Expanded Table2"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some syntax issues but close:

```
//Add columns with city
    #"Add City" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "City", each 
        if [Country] = "US" then  {"New York","Seattle","Miami"}
            else if [Country] = "UK" then  {"London","Birmingham"}
            else {"Tokyo","Osaka"}),
```